# How to access .war file on Amazon. What is the URL.

Tags: tomcat

Recently i deployed a war file on amazon using WinSCP. I don't know the URL to access it. I am able to run the file on my local system.

However i don't know the URL to access the same which as been deployed on Amazon EC2

Should i follow the Public IP mentioned in the Instance?

Kindly help me by giving the url/path

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL of your application will be something of the format

```
http://<ec2-PublicIp>:<Port-of-Tomcat>/yourApplicationName
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you WinScp-ed the file to the webapp folder of tomcat ?. If you haven't placed it in webapp folder then the deployment would have not happened.

In case if you have deployed the application properly then the default path for that application would be

```
http://public_ip:8080/application_name
```

this should work until you have changed the context in web.xml.

Comment: Thank you kannan, the path i specified is http://<public ip>:8080/jamwiki-1.3.2. 

Yes i deployed the war file using Winsp. The browser says "connection timed out". Earlier the message was "server not found". When i disabled the firewall/antivirus, the brower says "The server at <ip address> is taking too long to respond.".

Am i making a mistake?? Kindly let me know

Comment: As the browser says "connection timed out" it means that the tomcat is running but it is taking time to respond back. Mostly that its hung or in wierd state. Better restart tomcat and try again, and also do confirm if the WAR file that you have deployed got expanded/exploded.